# Error related to null reference to application context, reading nfc

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app, were on my second activity called NFCActivity I want to be able to read an NFC tag, i simply want the UTF-8 String, nothing else. My MainActivity is my login form, user will be automatically directed to the NFCActivity if logged in, (using sharedprefs)

I've not found any clear answers to my problem, or any simple solutions to my problem.
I feel like I've made a simple mistake somewhere, but can't figure it out.

I get an error : `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".NFCActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>


   @Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //Log.i("Foreground dispatch", "Discovered tag with intent: " + intent);
    // mText.setText("Discovered tag NDEF " + ++mCount + " with intent: " + intent);

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            NdefMessage[] msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }

            NdefMessage msg = msgs[0];

            try {
                //   mText.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload(), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My fault, mText was declared outside of onCreate